# is there a way to have different objects use different attach transforms in a socket interactor [unity 3d vr]

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

im trying to have different objects attach to the same socket interactor but use different attach transforms because the objects wont look right otherwise. i only see a way to set a socket interactors attach transform for every object that enters it

I've added in different objects to use as the attach transforms for the objects but I cant find a way to assign them to each object